# Magento duplicate Order Increment ID

Tags: php, magento

I’ve just upgraded Magento from 1.4.1.0 to the latest version (1.7.0.2) and I have this error when trying to place an order from frontend.

It’s about my orders’increment ids. I shall have a new order increment id according to the eav_entity_store table it should be :

M04001

But it proposes me M03454 when I try to reserve a new order increment id. This id is corresponding to the last order from the same customer.

If I use another customer account, I have another increment id, still the last of this other customer.

I don’t understand what’s happening, does someone already had this error ?

Regards,

Edit : When I try to order with a new account : no problem, if I try to make another order with this new account, still no problem, so problem seems to exist only for old account.

Comment: Indexes rebuilt? Cache cleared? Sure you are working with the same store you are looking at `eav_entity_store` table?

Comment: One index is not built, cache is cleared, I'm looking at the good store ;) 
If problem was located here, I'll not have the last order of this customer I guess, the problem should be under the quote_address refering to an old quote (addresses with the same id or something like that)

Comment: Please us me know if reindexing solved the problem.

Comment: I'm not able to reindex data, so I can't tell

Comment: What is the problem with reindexing?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this index problem, it's only on index 1 (attributes) and 4(products) I think it's not related to the bug I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the solution on the Magento forum : 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/errors.php/viewreply/408897/

copy

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php
```

change

```
$bind = array(’:increment_id’ => (int)$orderIncrementId);
```

to

```
$bind = array(’:increment_id’ => $orderIncrementId);
```

around line 165

This hotfix has been packaged in this extension : https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AlphaIncrement (thanks @NateFriedman)

Comment: It is bad practice to edit the Magento core.  This fix has been turned into an extension here: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_AlphaIncrement

Comment: For anyone reading this, don't mind with the extension package, the fix is now included in the last version of Magento (at least in Magento EE 1.14.3.7)